# Is Hilbert series a complete invariant

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Given a field $k$ and a graded polynomial, $S:=k[x_0,\cdots,x_n]$ and $I$ is an ideal of $S$.
Then one "could" compute the Hilbert series of $S/I$, which is an invariant of the quotient, i.e. it does not depend on the presentation of $I$.

If there are two quotient rings $S/I$ and $S/J$, with the same Hilbert series, can we know that $S/I\cong S/J$?

Comment: Take $I = \bigoplus_{k \geq d} S_k$ and $J = \bigoplus_{k \geq d'} S_k$ for $d \neq d'$.

Comment: @Daniel I was thinking Hilbert series ... sorry for the typo. I've corrected it.